# How to get Number of male and female friends and what is their percentage facebook apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
$query = 'SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and sex='male'';

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=" . urlencode($query) . 
     "&access_token=" . $access_token;
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents ($url));
$boys = count($data[data]);
echo $boys;
```

i have tried this method but unable to get the desired result...
I want to make an app like this

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be FQL, or are you willing to use the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, FQL does not support the SQL `COUNT()` function, which is what you need, here.

You would have to retrieve a list of friends' genders and loop over them.

In FQL: `SELECT sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Graph API: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=gender`

Comment: thanks for your reply but how can i count then ? because i have to display number of male and female friends..

Comment: Just use a `foreach` loop in your PHP script.

Answer (score -2):

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "FJgpERmm460"
   }
}
```